# C# .net Related to images

Tags: c#-4.0

I have following code in which I didn't get the meaning of:

```
double savesize = (8.0 * ((height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - 1)) / 1024;
```

So please help me.

**Code:**

```
    private void ImageBrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            loadedImagePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            imageTextBox.Text= loadedImagePath;
            loadedImage = Image.FromFile(loadedImagePath);
            height = loadedImage.Height;
            width = loadedImage.Width;
            loadedBitmap = new Bitmap(loadedImage);

            FileInfo imginf = new FileInfo(loadedImagePath);
            float size = (float)imginf.Length / 1024;
            SizeLabel.Text = size.ToString() + " KB";
            HeightLabel.Text = loadedImage.Height.ToString() + " Pixel";
            WidthLabel.Text = loadedImage.Width.ToString() + " Pixel";
            double savesize = (8.0 * ((height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - 1)) / 1024;
            SaveSizeLabel.Text = savesize.ToString() + " KB";
        }

    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an estimate of the number of KiloBytes required to save the image. To save as a bitmap (lossless) the formula would be (from [Zicara](http://www.zicara.com/techbytes/web-design/file-size-bitmap-image))

> File size in kilobytes = Resolution2 x Width x Height x Bits per
>   sample ÷ 8,192

In your example, I assume that the image isn't being saved as a bitmap, but instead in a lossy format that produces files of that size given images of those dimensions - seeing how you actually persist the files may enable a little more light to be shed.